# Can someone explain the approach for this problem statement. I am stuck

Tags: algorithm

An n*m grid of bulbs was given. Some were on (denoted by ‘O’) and some were off (denoted by ‘X’). When you toggle the state of a bulb, the state of the bulbs adjacent to it gets toggled too. Return the minimum number of toggles needed to switch all the bulbs off or -1 if it is not possible.

Comment: Do adjacent bulbs get toggled regardless of their state? Or only to the same state you are toggling? Example: If your grid is like [O, X] and you turn off the first one, does the second one get turned on, or does it remain turned off? Do toggles propagate recursively?

Comment: the magic google words are "lights out puzzle"

Comment: Does "adjacent" include diagonally adjacent or only horizontally and vertically adjacent?